# Append to series produces empty result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on some homework with Pandas. I have been trying to create a list from matching conditions:

```
lst = []

for word in nhl_df['teamname']:
    for name in cities['NHL']:
        if re.search(word, name):
            lst.append(cities['Metropolitan area'][cities['NHL'] == name])
```

The output is as following:

```
[16    Tampa Bay Area
 Name: Metropolitan area, dtype: object,
 7    Boston
 Name: Metropolitan area, dtype: object,
 13    Toronto
 Name: Metropolitan area, dtype: object, ....
```

However, while I use a series instead of list:

```
lst = pd.Series(dtype = str)
for word in nhl_df['teamname']:
    for name in cities['NHL']:
        if re.search(word, name):
            lst.append(cities['Metropolitan area'][cities['NHL'] == name])
```

The result will come out empty. I can see that each of my output values is object. How shall I solve this issue?

Thank you so much for your time and help in solving this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
lst = lst.append(cities['Metropolitan area'][cities['NHL'] == name])
```

in the last statement instead of just `lst.append(...)`.

You have to reassign it to itself for a series as the update is not in place.

Comment: Thank you! I always miss these things in Pandas.